# How to pass duration to lilypond function

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

I defined a simple function:

```
disdn =
#(define-music-function
     (d)
     (ly:duration?)
   #{
    <dis ais dis g>#d
   #})
```

I am calling it as follows:

```
\disdn #8
```

I am getting an error:

```
wrong type for argument 1.  Expecting duration, found 8
```

What is the correct syntax for passing a duration? Please provide documentation reference as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call your function either like this

```
\disdn 8
```

or like this

```
\disdn #(ly:make-duration 3)
```

When you write `#8` you tell Lilypond to use the guile object `8`, which is a number. But if you write `8` the parser will try to properly interpret this and will interpret this as duration.

For your code to work though you’d need to write

```
disdn =
#(define-music-function
     (d)
     (ly:duration?)
   #{
    <dis ais dis g>$d
   #})
```

Check the documentation for the difference between `#` and `$`: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/extending/lilypond-scheme-syntax

Basically `#` will mean the expression is lexed and then evaluated later by the parser. Meanwhile `$` will mean that the expression is evaluated while it is being lexed, and the parser will parse the already evaluated expression. So writing

```
<...>#d
```

the parser will see `<...>` followed by a scheme expression and thus first evaluates `<...>` with the previous duration and then evaluates the scheme expression. But if you do

```
<dis ais dis g>$d
```

the parser will see `<...>` followed by a duration, and will thus evaluate this with the given duration.

Comment: I do not know why, but this site seems to turn <something>$d into a TAB clef ...

Comment: Also, is the "3" supposed to be an "8" in your second code block?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace No. `ly:make-duration` takes a duration-log, so for a whole note we use 0, for a half 1, for a quarter 2, for an eigth 3 &c.

Comment: *(cleaning up my previous comments)*  
The site is trying render the Markdown code block as ABCjs (a similar bug sometimes happens with jTab).  
To prevent this, use the HTML preformatted text delimiters `<pre>` & `</pre>` around the code block, and replace angle brackets `<` & `>` with their HTML entities `&lt;` & `&gt;`.